# How to make the thickness of traffic volume flow symbology proportional to traffic counts?

Tags: qgis, transportation, flow-map, traffic

I can scale the bandwidth proportionally to the traffic volumes; however, I cannot show the directionality of the movements. Volumes for directional moves are stored in two different columns of a database. My workaround for this is to import the layer twice and use two different symbologies, one for each direction. **Is it to possible to do this without having to import the same layer twice?**

Note that I need to show the bandwidth starting from the link so I cannot use the same offset because it create blank space between the opposite directions (it seems to me that the offset start from the middle of the thckness).

**Edit:** in the uploaded images you can see that the offset depends on the width of the links, so I is not possible to find a single offset value matching for all the links

[image: Not Desired Effect]

[image: Desired Effect]

Comment: Could you upload a image of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please also provide a sample of your road layer's attribute table

Comment: Major issue is that if you want the lines to be of consistent thickness in pixels as the user zooms in and out, then the offset must change at every zoom level so they continue to touch without overlapping.  Which argues for a client-side geometry rendering, but that requires custom coding with javascript and SVG (or whatever) and may not be performant for large numbers of geometries.

Comment: Well, my aim is to start the bandwith from the link. If I understand well the offset is localized at the middle of the bandwith and not at the beginning. I need to expand the bandwith starting from the link: up for direction1, down for direction2

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're looking at doing something similar to [this](http://www.caliper.com/transcad/IntersectionDiagram.png)

Comment: Yes. Similar because I need that the bandwith start from the road line. So I need to have the flow1 close to flow2, witouh any blank space.

Comment: @NathanW IF you see the picture I included in my previous comment, is it possible to do this with QGIS at the moment?

Comment: @dassouki I think it is possible but you have to use different shape files. If you opne another thread we can detail the question

Comment: @Giulio I don't want another thread, I was trying to understand your question

Comment: @dassouki sorry for the misunderstanding and thanks for your effort...I hope to solve this problem quickly

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 2.x, this should be possible using data-defined offset together with data-defined line width.